# There are two buttons initially aligned horizontally but, If we increase the text of one button then two buttons should aligned vertically in Scss

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is the html for two buttons, if initially there are two buttons aligned horizontally

But when we are trying to increase the text of one button then two buttons should be aligned vertically, How we can achieve these using css?

I have tried using if else in saas but its not working for me

```css
.purchase_cart_quanitity_group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.purchase_cart_favorited & {
    column-gap: 24px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="purchase_cart_quanitity_group">
   <div class="purchase_cart_quantity">
      <div class="input-group --count">
           <div class="input-group-wrapper">
              <buton class="input__button btn --secondary --sm minus">
          <svg class="icon icon_minus">
           <use href="/resources/images/icons.svg#minus"></use>
          </svg>
         </buton>
             <input class="input__field" type="number" step="1" name="" id="input-1" min="1" 
              required="" placeholder="1" disabled="">
            <buton class="input__button btn --secondary --sm plus">
         <svg class="icon icon_plus">
         <use href="/resources/images/icons.svg#plus"></use>
         </svg>
        </buton>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="purchase_cart_add_button">
    <div class="button button_primary button_sm button_ button_has_text">
       <a class="cmp-button" href="#" data-rippleria="" style="overflow: hidden;">
         <span class="cmp-button__icon"></span>
         <span class="cmp-button__text">Add To Cart</span>
       </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `flex-wrap:wrap` property to change the direction flow if override the div's width

```
.purchase_cart_quanitity_group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```